# Regularization on small dataset with n/p < 10

Tags: linear-model, regularization

I am approaching to regularization methods and I understood they are useful for simplifying complex models with a lot of variables. Now I have a doubt...
In case I have a small dataset, with few variables (p), but also few observations (n), so that the number of p compared to n is still high (for example p=10 and n=30, thus n/p < 10), does make it sense to apply regularization (Lasso, Ridge or Enet)?